# Rails 3.1: Views not rendering in namespace layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, namespaces, view, rendering

In routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
    root :controller => "base", :action => "index"
    resources :products
end
```

The products controller inherits from the base controller:

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
   #layout 'admin'
   def index
   end
end

class Admin::ProductsController < Admin::BaseController
   def index
   end
end
```

Without "layout 'admin'", both index views render normally.

With "layout 'admin'", the admin layout is rendered, but the views are not rendered, despite WEBricks message:

```
Rendered admin/products/index.html.erb within layouts/admin
```

Comment: When I had this, I almost always had forgotten the yield call or the "=" before it. Do you have that?

Answer (score 4):

`<%= yield %>` might help there, mate

Comment: +1 for this :D hahah I was laughing for few minutes after reading ;)